# how i can display arabic letters in cmd

Tags: cmd, arabic, letters

can any one give my solution to display the arabic letters in cmd

i tried to use chcp 1256 and chcp 62001 in cmd but it does not show the arabic letters correctly

but when i search in the internet i found someone who said there is solution but it needs some files in windows 95 or windows 98 but i am not sure if he lying or not

if there is files to display the arabic letters in cmd in windows 95 or windows 98 can any one upload those files to me or give me solution to display arabic letters in cmd

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/487819/how-do-i-view-unicode-characters-on-command-prompt

Comment: May I ask *why* you need this? It seems like most cases where you need Arabic letters in a command prompt would warrant a more extensible UI base.

Comment: jackjop (it does not work) it tell me "The system cannot write to the specified device" when i write "chcp 65001" in cmd

Comment: Matthew Haugen "i need this because i am from arabic country and i made program and i want to support arabic menu on it"

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821083/), it is not possible to write arabic characters in the console even if you change the codepage or the font because *it is not supported* in the cmd  prompt as a consequence it will not be displayed correctly.

**update:**

Even if you try to use third party monospaced fonts like [this](http://www.userbooster.de/support/feature-artikel/unicode-support-in-openldap-for-windows.aspx) that will not show characters as expected.